# Session Validation and Expiration

Tags: django, session-cookies

I am currently reading about session expiration and I am curious as to how django would know if a session expired ? Currently I have read about reading and writing to sessions in Django and how to set expiration of a session but have not encountered anything on validating a session. How do I know if a session is still Valid using Django ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Expire time for session using set_expire function:

```
request.session.set_expiry(300)
```

You can validate session using is_authenticated function:

```
request.user.is_authenticated()
```

Comment: @JamesFranco So, this is what you need :)

Comment: This does not imply any permissions and doesn’t check if the user is active or has a valid session.